# Checking if Split method is empty

Tags: c#, methods, split

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace switchStatementExercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String response;

            Console.WriteLine("Please Vote for your president out of the 7 following, Joseph Mason, James Long, Ben Harding, Georgia Mason, Keith Webb, Mark Grimley, Max Gridley");
            response = Console.ReadLine();

            string fullNameJoe = response;
            var names = fullNameJoe.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string firstName = names[0];
            string lastName = names[1];
            Console.WriteLine(lastName);
            if (response.Equals(fullNameJoe) || response.Equals(firstName) || response.Equals(lastName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You have voted for " + fullNameJoe);
                Console.WriteLine(fullNameJoe);

            }
            else if (fullNameJoe.Length > 1 && lastName == null)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You need a last name");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a first name and last name");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So what i'm trying to do is check if the last name is empty it was all the user to enter a last name, but I am getting this error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>      at switchStatementExercise.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\cSharpWeek1\switchStatementExercise\switchStatementExercise\Program.cs:line 21

Any help or redirection to the answer would be great!

Comment: Why `fullNameJoe.Split(new[] {';'}` and not `fullNameJoe.Split(new[] {' '}`. Who will write `Max;Gridley`

Comment: I've tried this and that still doesn't work ):

Comment: It only works according to what you're typing. You can split by any characters `fullNameJoe.Split(" ,;-/".ToCharArray()`

Comment: I just tried that and I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

means, whatever you typed in there, you didn't get `names[1]` (most likely) after `Split`. So, if you typed "alex;" - forget about.

You can check

```
if (names.Length < 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You need first and last name");
    return;
}
```

On another note, why ";"? It will expect typing "alex;morgan". We usually type "alex morgan" and do split by " ". You can use split by any of characters

```
fullNameJoe.Split(" ,;-/".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

In the second part

```
if (response.Equals(fullNameJoe) || response.Equals(firstName) || response.Equals(lastName
```

this doesn't make much sense. The first condition will always be true. The second and third condition will true or false. What you probably need to do is Create a list

```
var presidents = "Joseph Mason, James Long, Ben Harding, Georgia Mason, Keith Webb, Mark Grimley, Max Gridley".
    Split(",".ToCharArray()).Select(p => p.Trim()).ToArray()
```

And then check for condition number one (optional) [`if (names.Length < 2)`]. Or you can go directly to name checking

```
if (names.Contains(response.Trim(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("yes"); 
}
```

Comment: I've changed my code back to the empty space in between ""

Comment: @J.mason I don't agree, I just fiddled it `var fullNameJoe = "alex morgan";
        var names = fullNameJoe.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine(names[0]); 
     Console.WriteLine(names[1]);` **works like a charm**

Comment: But with this dont you need a name as a place holder? I just tried your code and it worked but how about if I want a space between the user entry?

Comment: @J.mason see my updated answer. I think your logic is wrong

Comment: Does this mean I need to change my variables at the top then?

Comment: @J.mason if your goal is to check that president "selected" (types into console) is one of the guys in the list - yea, you don't need most of that code - only do what I posted in part 2. Namely - create list and check if the input is matching one of the entries in the list.

Comment: Hmm okay I think I get what you mean, But i just gave it a go and still getting an error I think i'm abit confused ngl to you! @T.S.